# Increase count of three column based on specific value in single column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns pkey and role

[image: Table structure]

I need the o/p table as below

[image: O/p Table]

The logic behind the table is if the role is configurator then count of config = 1 and count of review should increased by 1 and count of abstractor increased by 1

Also if the role is reviewer then the count of reviewer should be 1 and count of abstractor should increased by 1.

I have tried the below code but cant derive the o/p.

```
SELECT 
    lease_pkey, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_role IN( 'Abstractor') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AbstractorChagnes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_role IN( 'Reviewer') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Reviewer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_role IN( 'Project Owner TL','Configurator') THEN  Reviewer = Reviewer+1 ELSE 0 END) AdminChanges
FROM 
    v_audit_trail_trans
GROUP BY 
    lease_pkey
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the conditions for increasing reviewer and abstractor in their own counters:

```
SELECT lease_pkey, 
SUM(CASE WHEN user_role IN( 'Abstractor','Configurator','Reviewer') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AbstractorChagnes,
SUM(CASE WHEN user_role IN( 'Reviewer','Configurator') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Reviewer,
...
FROM v_audit_trail_trans
GROUP BY lease_pkey
```